# R plotting factor with values on y-axis

Tags: r, plot, axis-labels

```
f <- as.factor(sample( rep(c("a", "b", "c"), 3)))

plot(1:9,f)
```

gives the values 1.0..3.0 on the y-axis.

How do I get the values of f ("a", "b" and "c") on the y-axis?

Comment: In 2 steps: `plot(1:9, f, yaxt = "n"); axis(2, 1:3, levels(f))`.

Comment: Thanks. It works like a charm. If you add it as an answer, I will close the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
f <- as.factor(sample( rep(c("a", "b", "c"), 3)))
```

**R base**

```
plot(1:9, f, yaxt = "n")
axis(2, 1:3, levels(f))
```

**lattice**

```
see fdetsch answer
```

**ggplot2**

```
library(ggplot2)
qplot(seq_along(f), f)
```

Comment: A very comprehensive overview. Nice!

Answer (score 1):

It's quite easy using **lattice**.

```
library(lattice)
xyplot(f ~ 1:length(f))
```

[image: xyplot]